# magento 1.7.0.0 unable to print invoice

Tags: magento, printing

when i click print invoice in a magento invoice if im in chrome instead of the pdf download it just gives me a blank page, if im in IE it gives me a 500 internal server error.

i already tried the magento cleanup script, reindex, cache and recompile and nothing

can you give me a hand?

Comment: Can you provide more details? If you inspect the request with developer tools (both browsers has it) you should be able to see the reason for that 500 error.

Comment: Also you should check the log on the server side - you should get enough valuable pointers from there.

Comment: i have looked, but i really don't see any error in the tools, should i be looking in something in particular?

Comment: i activated log's in the developer tab, but nothing appear, it appears to be more of a lame problem with me as if i right click in the print link i can save the pdf but if i click it gives me a blank page i tought it could be some problem with the browser but the same thing happen in other borwsers

Comment: my brain should be damaged today for sure, of course i can print, i print the page displayed in the browser, not the pdf magento should give me. can't find any errors, maybe im not looking in the right place. as you may have noticed, im not a great tech in magento :(

Comment: tried to change php version to 5.3 instead of 5.4 it worked, i think there is a patch from magento for it to work with 5.4, let's see if it works, also find these http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17902/cant-generate-pdf-invoices-or-packing-slips-in-magento but if the patch works i prefer it to change the magento code.

Answer (score 1):

did not get many help with you guy's but i will post the awnser that i found for my own problem you just install the patch SUPEE-2629 for compatibility with php 5.4 you can find it here

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download